# How to add a CSS table-striped class to dynamically generated row in jQuery Datatable?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, datatable

So I know that if you do addClass(myCSSClass), it should add said class to the datatable row.

My problem is that this doesn't seem to work.

My code is like below:

```
var table = ('#datatable').Datatable();
table.row.add(['<button type="button" id="Details">A button</button>']).addClass("success").draw();
```

The addClass() function is mentioned in the datatables documentation. But it doesn't work with *bootstrap table-striped class* **success**.

I need the *table-striped class* **'success'** to be added to the row I am creating in my Datatable. How can I get this to work?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think its just $(row).addClass("success") as in this example datatables.net/reference/option/createdRow

(Quoting a comment by @Brent Boden) Thanks for the quick reply! :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the css classes, you can just add these css to your code.

```
tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
   background-color: #ccc; `the color you prefer`
}

tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
   background-color: #fff; `the color you prefer`
}
```

Anonther thing you can try is to write code in the row created callback, more information about this can be found here:

https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/row_callback.html

Comment: To give some background to where I'm coming from, I need to set a class based on some condition, like if(something has happened) then set class "success", else set class "warning".

Comment: @Anusha i just added the documentation over the "rowCreated" callback of the datatable

Comment: I was looking though that. :) So, when I want to select an entire row, then I should do $('tr', row).addClass('success') ??

Comment: Do help out, I'm very very new to jQuery itself, and have absolutely no clue about how to do things with it. :)

Comment: I think its just $(row).addClass("success") as in this example https://datatables.net/reference/option/createdRow

Answer (score 0):

It is because you trying add class to not existing object.
Try my snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#datatable').DataTable();
    table.row.add(['<button type="button" id="Details">A button</button>']).draw();
    $('#datatable').find('tr').last().addClass("success");
});
```

```css
tr.success { background-color:green !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table id="datatable" class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @Anusha So there is something that you don't tell us, as you can see above snippet work well in my example, class is appended, background of row is changed.

Comment: Could be I'm missing something important. It's part of a larger project, so it could be that I'm missing out on something in all the code it has. :(